# Creating a simple questioneer that simialar to a choose your own adventure, text only

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to do this little questioner for a friend of mine, want to start off with just a simple yes or no question. If she picks 'yes' then a small detailed message appears. If picks 'no' she'll get a your no fun or something like that message. I can figure out how to keep the message hidden, yet appear once a certain button is pressed. any ideas? this is what I have so far. I'm just a novice when it comes to JS

```
        <!-- insert clickable box here -->

    <p id="q1">Want to play a game?</p>
    <br>
    <button type="button1" onclick="buttonYes()">Yes</button>
    <button type="button2" onclick="buttonNo()">No</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function buttonYes() {
            document.getElementById("yes").innerHTML = msg;
        }
    </script>

    <p id="yes" style="display: none;">random words</p>

    <p id="none" style="display: none;">no words</p>

    <!-- if yes, show detailed message -->

    <!-- if no, show thanks for playing -->


    <!-- if yes, followed by detailed message, insert question #2 here -->

    <!-- if yes to question #2, give instructions on what to do -->

    <!-- if no to question #2, order soda, game ends -->
```

If I can at least figure out the first part, I can easily do the rest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: first: make your html correct. `type="button1"` is not valid. button1 is no valid value for the property type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("yes").style.display = "block";
```

This would be the quick answer. I'd suggest looking [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your html structure a little bit and with a small portion of javascript code you can build the whole logic.

I made a fiddle for you: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/935v33sn/1/)

it works as follows: all questions are wrapped up in a container. all questions are not visible (CSS) except the first one (CSS).

Now take a look at the js code: it selects all buttons and assign a click handler to it. if a button is pressed it prevents the form submission. Next it reads out the question id (could also work with `actualQuestion`. Like you want). In the next line it reads out if the user clicked on yes or no and show the detail for the corresponding button click.

Now it selects all details for "yes clicks". If it is shown and clicked be the user it shows the next question (display="none" for the actual question and display="block" for the next question). If it's a detail for the click on a no button nothing happens.